# login sql throws java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 3 > 2 in Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Below codes are Spring Boot login configuration using Spring Boot Security.
First

**== application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?characterEncoding=utf8&serverTimezone=Asia/Seoul
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = password

spring.queries.users-query = SELECT username, password FROM blog_user WHERE username=?
spring.queries.roles-query = SELECT username, role FROM blog_user WHERE username=?
```

**== spring security configuration**

```
@Value("${spring.queries.users-query}")
private String usersQuery;

@Value("${spring.queries.roles-query}")
private String rolesQuery;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery).authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
                .dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/" ,"/home*", "/js/**", "/css/**", "/icon/**", "/users/login", "/users/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/users*", "/posts/**").hasAnyRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/users/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
                .and()
            .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/error/403");
}
```

But login line throws the following exceptions.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 3 > 2. 
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
```

I know this exception is thrown from sql PreparedStatementCallback method. But I am afraid I have no idea where the `spring.queris.users-query` statement is related with spring security part, so I can fix this preparedstatement parameter. I am a beginner in Spring Security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your SQL query is searching for 3 values in 3 different columns and it finds only 2 columns in the selected table. The queries from the `application.properties` file are the only ones?

I think that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725814/spring-security-java-sql-sqlexception-column-index-out-of-range-3-2) will also help you.

Maybe you can print the entire stacktrace here with the sql statement printed and also the structure of USERS and ROLES tables.

Comment: You are right. I modified the user sql to "SELECT username, password, role FROM blog_user WHERE username=?" Then It worked perfectly. I appreciate your smart reply.